# When I update my Android Support Library to 23.0.1, there is a error that miss library of 22.1.1

Tags: android, sdk

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':MaterialLibs:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1.

```
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
     file:/B:/Android/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
     file:/B:/Android/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar
     file:/B:/Android/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.pom
     file:/B:/Android/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar

 Required by:
     FamilyHealthTracker:MaterialLibs:unspecified
```

> Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1.

```
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.1.1/cardview-v7-22.1.1.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.1.1/cardview-v7-22.1.1.jar
     file:/B:/Android/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.1.1/cardview-v7-22.1.1.pom
     file:/B:/Android/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.1.1/cardview-v7-22.1.1.jar
     file:/B:/Android/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.1.1/cardview-v7-22.1.1.pom
     file:/B:/Android/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/22.1.1/cardview-v7-22.1.1.jar
 Required by:
     FamilyHealthTracker:MaterialLibs:unspecified
```

Comment: Check this location -> file:/B:/Android/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.1.1/appcompat-v7-22.1.1.jar   Is jar file is there?

Comment: just  have  recyclerview-v7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please download 'cardview-v7-22.1.1.jar' by SDK Manager:

1. Download library from this dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5eeiwpsfddaeacf/AABbECqCGymNy0XqXwpyX9PAa?dl=0)
2. Copy and paste this folder to

   **your sdk path\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support**
3. Restart Android Studio and build project.

Comment: @Sweet Lollipop : and please download all components needed in android sdk manager..!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks it's working

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com."
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```